# Half Bridge SMPS design

Tags: power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, bridge-rectifier

I'm trying to design a half-bridge SMPS. However not able to get the desired output. My doubt lies in the transformer sizing and it's implementation in LTspice.

Specs:

- Vs=220 V RMS AC
- Desired DC output: Vo=480 V

Duty cycle taken for the half bridge=0.45

After calculation, I got for L1=1; L2=L3=12 for LTspice.

However, the output voltage is quite small. What can be done for this?

LTspice file img attached

[image]

Comment: It is very likely that it comes from the upper source \$V_1\$ which should be referenced to MOSFET \$M_1\$ source (middle point) and not ground. Also the peak voltage of each source should be 12-15 V, not 2.5 V as I think it is. Also, for a more realistic value, the mag. inductance of your transformer should be 1-10 mH, not a 1 henry.

Comment: ...and also you cannot have 1N4148 for the output diodes : )

Comment: _"What can be done for this?"_ Instead of checking the far-right output and concluding it's too low, please start on the left side of the schematic and check yourself forward node by node.

Comment: ...or for the input bridge rectifier unless you want a recti-fryer. Numbers please; not "quite small" or "not able to get the desired output". What made you choose a 1 kHz switching frequency?

Comment: @VerbalKint I tried to change the mosfet Von to 12V, however the output still comes in mV. As far as the inductance is considered, I tried to replicate the ratio that I got from the number of turns i.e. L1/L2 = 1/12 hence, I tried taking this as is.. when I tried taking the values as 1mH and 12mH, the simulation slows down and output voltage starts at nV as opposed to mV from the previous case.

Comment: @VerbalKint I tried changing the output diodes to ideal ones, however the voltage still is in mV

Comment: Do you have experience in power electronics because you want to design a converter operated from the mains and this is a dangerous business in essence if you are not acquainted with the dangers of high-voltage? For your simulation, a) make sure first that the junction of M1 and M2 swings between 0 - 400 V and b) use a transformer model as the values you have passed for your inductors are in henry. Also remove the front-end rectifier and use a 400-V source where \$R_1\$ (useless by the way) is connected.

Comment: @VerbalKint Protection circuitry such as Inrush current protection, EMI filters, OC and Ov protection I will put at a later stage when the design is correct and output voltage of 480V is achieved.  For a half-bridge converter based SMPS, what topology for AC-DC conversion would you suggest?

Comment: If no galvanic isolation is needed, I would go for a boost topology. What power is wanted?

Comment: @VerbalKint It is a high-voltage low power application. The specs mentioned above are taken just to test the circuit and the calculations. However, the final specs at the output required are: 10kV, 5mA

Comment: @VerbalKint however, if is it required to only use the half-bridge topology, what should be the approach?

Comment: This was resolved when I tried this simulation using plecs and definitely getting the output as 10kV and 5mA. Thank you all for help.